# Angular material layout broken with Iphone 5c & 6

Tags: iphone, angularjs, angular-material

I'm working on a website with angular-material. Everything works well except with mobile view on IOS.

- **Iphone**: 5c or 6
- **IOS version**: 8.1 or 9

Here's a screen shot, on the left part the good rendering on Android, on the right, the IOS one.

[image: Compared rendering]

The only difference beteween IOS & Android is the store button shown (Play for android, AppStore for IOS) but I tried to remove them already. The code can be inspected directly on http://www.luditeam.com

Did I miss something? Is it a known problem?

Thanks in advance.